# Cron Wordpress 4.7.14 - will not send scheduled emails

Tags: civimail

I schedule a job through mailings.  The Cron job looks like it picks it up, and the mailing is marked as running, but it never gets sent out until someone manually runs scheduled jobs (administer>system>scheduled jobs).
The process is running every 15 minutes on schedule, the jobs logs, has two entries at the time it should pick up the scheduled job.
The first just has the time/date and
Summary
Starting scheduled jobs execution
the second has the date/time the jo
Entity: Job Action: process_mailing 
Summary
Starting execution of test job schedled - 
Details
Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}
Full message: 
Starting execution of test job schedled
but once it picks up a scheduled job it never completes, it will just generating the starting execution message.  Also as a result of this I get the system message that Cron is not running after a bit.   I've tried Civihosting support and they said to post it here.

Comment: Aidan, Thank you!  It was an out of memory issue.  When I went to run the cron job manually from cpanel, the error appeared.  I contacted the hosting support, they increased the memory,  problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Is there any output from the cron job?  (On Civihosting, you can configure the cron job to mail you the output.)  If it is starting but not completing, it could be running out of memory.

Comment: Thank you, Aidan,   It was a memory  problem, when I ran the cron from control panel - got the memory limit error, but then it disappeared, after contacting support they increased memory and now the scheduled jobs run.